# App crashes on device but XCode doesn't register a crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, console, crash

I have my device plugged in and I'm running my app through XCode.
At a certain point, the app crashes on the device and exits out to the home screen. However, Xcode still shows the app as "Running" and I have the option to click "Stop" - it is not grayed out. No error message is printed to the console, and no crash log is saved to the device log.

I need to fix the crash, but without an error message I'm having a hard time tracking down the problem. I've placed `NSLog` statements in key areas of the code but haven't gotten any closer to figuring out what is causing the crash.

Does anybody know anything about the strange fact that XCode doesn't know that my app has crashed and still shows the app as "Running"?

Answer (score 4):

To help with the debugging part of your question, you can set "Strip Debug Symbols" to "No" in your build settings:

[image: ss]

and then you will be able to see a symbolicated crash log in the "Device Logs" section of the Organizer window:

[image: ss2]

Comment: Thanks - I set the values to No but I didn't get crash logs for my crash that XCode isn't recognizing as a crash.

Answer (score 3):

If the app is signed for distribution, X-Code can't debug it.  Launching the app onto a device results in X-Code not being able to get a process id.

You can still get your log messages (and other console messages, hopefully including crash information) via the organizer -> devices -> console.

If your app is signed for development and this is still a problem, you have a deeper issue here that is causing X-Code to think that your app wasn't able to start.  Look into how long it takes your app to initialize; I've had issues where load times > 10 seconds left X-Code not getting a process ID but the app still running.

Worse case scenario, load NSLog messages like crazy, install the app and run it until it crashes.  Then immediately load organizer,  go to the device, and download the console, then look for any crash logs.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, App crashed without any log or error.My error was related to "objc_msgSend".

To find out your error - Select "Show the Debug Navigator" from Xcode Navigator window(A left side window). My App shows "objc_msgSend" in Thread 1 at first line.

So I have google about "objc_msgSend" and found that this crash happens because of a memory error. it means that a message has been sent to a receiver which has already been deallocated.

To trace this error use "NSZombieEnabled environment variable"

1. From Xcode,click on Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme.
2. From "Run scheme" configuration, go to the "Diagnostics" tab.
3. Under "Memory Management" check the checkbox beside "Enable Zombie Objects".

Now, Run your App and Regenerate Crash, This time you will find crash report on console.

```
*** -[WSAddressViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1683d1b0
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a breakpoint on the line by accident?

[image: Screenshot of breakpoint]

Disable or delete the breakpoint.